# atom-java-snippets: Render the snippets.cson file in real-time before typing prefix in java file?

Tags: java, code-snippets

**Hello world!** My name is Hank Igoe and this is my first time posting. I've been using atom-java-snippets with the Atom IDE, and they work great. There is one minor tweak I'd love to have, though. It would be nice to have a WYSIWYG pane for the 'body' section that showed what it would look like after rendering from the snippets.cson file.

For example, here's a snippet to make a Java interface:

```
'snippet-interface':
  'prefix': 'iface'
  'body': 'public interface ${1:IfaceName} {\n
    ${2:METHODS}\n}${3}'
```

It's not that hard to read, but it would be great if there were a third pane that showed the rendered version of the body, like this:

`public interface IfaceName { 
   METHODS
 }`

Then I would know it's ready for the code file, and could quit tweaking it to get the spacing right, etc. Of course, you can do this manually by going to the java file, typing the prefix, see what the .cson snippet prints out, then tweak the .cson file if the formatting is off, and lather rinse repeat until it's just right. But I was thinking it would be nice to have the instant feedback that you get when, say, doing html/markup editing in an editor that can do realtime updates.

Anyway, I hope that question is clear, please feel free to post a question if you need clarification.

btw, if such a thing doesn't exist but you all think it's a good feature and would like to add it to atom-java-snippets or create a new plugin, I'd be happy to help out if I can.

Thanks in advance for any advice,
Hank
http://linkedin.com/in/hank-igoe-27419519b/
http://github.com/vujadetech
http://facebook/hank.igoe54